# Method reference of a method reference in a Lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, method-reference

I am new in Java 8, and I have this expression:

```
 .map(mc -> mc.getName().getDefaultName())
```

and I would like to know if it could be replaced for something like:

```
.map(TeleBadalonaCampaignType::getName::getDefaultName)
```

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters in title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nope, not really - the language has no such construct; unless you map it twice:

```
.map(TeleBadalonaCampaignType::getName)
.map(WhateverObject::getDefaultName)
```